# Setting a VIM bookmark

Tags: vim, vi, bookmarks

How you can set a bookmark in vim?  I want to bookmark some lines and functions. How do you make a bookmark on the code?  My code is written in C.

Comment: You might consider looking at [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net). It integrates really well with vim. It allows you to jump to function definitions. Relevant help section in vim `:h tagsrch.txt`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you type `ma` , it will create bookmark on the current line at the current location with name `a`.

for example, typing `ma` has created a bookmark at the exact location where the cursor is highlighted

[image]

To Access Bookmarked Line Inside Vi you can use
- {macro-name}

backtick followed by the macro name. Move to the exact bookmark location. This will jump to the exact character location within the line from where it was bookmarked earlier.

For example, if you type `a , it will take you to the bookmark with name “a”. i.e It will take you to the place where the cursor is high-lighted in the above Fig 1.

```
`a
```

[source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/02/how-to-add-bookmarks-inside-vi-and-vim-editor/)

Comment: looks like the backtick goes to the exact spot on the line, while the single quote goes to the beginning of the line.

Comment: now how do I remove a bookmark

Comment: To delete bookmarks execute `:delmarks {bookmark-name}` e.g. `:delmarks a`. Found that [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vim/vim_markers.htm).

Answer (score 36):

To jump to a mark enter an apostrophe (') or backtick (`) followed by a letter. Using an apostrophe jumps to the beginning of the line holding the mark, while a backtick jumps to the line and column of the mark.

Using a lowercase letter (for example `a) will only work if that mark exists in the current buffer. Using an uppercase letter (for example `A) will jump to the file and the position holding the mark (you do not need to open the file prior to jumping to the mark).

- Each file can have mark **a** – use a lowercase mark to jump within a file.
- There is only one file mark **A** – use an uppercase mark to jump between files.

> Command   Description

**ma**     set mark a at current cursor location

**'a**     jump to line of mark a (first non-blank character in line)

**`a**  jump to position (line and column) of mark a

**d'a** delete from current line to line of mark a

**d`a** delete from current cursor position to position of mark a

**c'a** change text from current line to line of mark a

**y`a** yank text to unnamed buffer from cursor to position of mark a

**:marks**  list all the current marks

**:marks aB**   list marks a, B

[Reference from Vim Wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks)

Comment: Love the single quote instead of the tick... the tick is awkward when you go keyboard-only.

Comment: To add to the navigation tips, use the following to iterate through existing marks:  
]` jump to position of next mark  
[` jump to position of previous mark

Answer (score 31):

Capital letters let you set global bookmarks (i.e. in all buffers/tabs).

So you can use `mA` to set global bookmark `A`, then use `'A` to get to that bookmarked place even if you're editing a different file.